# How to make clickable row link to a different page

Tags: c#, jquery

I have this bit of working code, but cannot figure out how to change it to do what I need.

Currently, it is a table of clickable rows, the row links to the "authid" page, which corresponds to the authid value on the table.

I need to make it so it still links to the correct authid page but I need to remove the authid row.

```
<tr id="ClickableRow" class="@style">
<td>@Html.ActionLink(@auth.AuthID + " - Details", "Details", new { id = auth.AuthID })</td>
<td>...........</td>
</tr>

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr#ClickableRow').click(function () {
            var url = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
    }
```

So currently it works to link to the correct page, but I can't figure out how to make it link without having to use the a:first method, because I need to delete that authid row.

I'm really new to this all, any help is appreciated. Links to good videos or resources would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you simply want to remove the `<a>` element, and have the row "know" the url without it?

Comment: I need to remove the first <td> element, and still have the row link to that same page, if that helps.

Comment: could you post the html Dom structure of the whole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `data-attribute` on the `<tr>` to hold your target url, and the navigate to that address on your event.

```
<tr id="ClickableRow" class="@style" data-authurl="@Url.Action(auth.AuthID + " - Details", "Details", new { id = auth.AuthID })">
<td>...........</td>
</tr>

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tr#ClickableRow').click(function () {
            var url = $(this).data('authurl');
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
    }
```

Comment: Works great, you're the bomb. Will tag as answer.